# How to get time difference between multiple entries by user id?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create an attendance kind of table I get the value from punch machine like this :

```
UID  |  Time
023  |  2019-01-29 20:06:53
023  |  2019-01-29 20:07:10
023  |  2019-01-29 20:22:05
123  |  2019-01-30 08:57:01
027  |  2019-01-30 09:14:14
023  |  2019-01-30 11:22:21
123  |  2019-01-30 18:35:53
027  |  2019-01-30 19:00:25
```

Now all the entries in one table so I want the first and last entry of user and group by date then get time difference from 2 values

I need Output like this :

```
UID  |  In Time               |  Out Time              |  Time Diff.
023  |  2019-01-29 20:06:53   |  2019-01-29 20:22:05   |  00:18:00
027  |  2019-01-30 09:14:14   |  2019-01-30 19:00:25   |  10:00:00
123  |  2019-01-30 08:57:01   |  2019-01-30 18:35:53   |  10:00:00
```

first i'm try to get data like this but this is not working for me

```
$select =  mysqli_query ($db, "SELECT *, Min(Date) AS MinDate, Max(Date) AS MaxDate FROM demotable GROUP BY UID");
```

Comment: I assume UID has a primary or unique key otherwise your SQL query is incorrect for MySQL to handle

Comment: Yes UID id is the unique id of the user

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`TIMEDIFF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff):

```
SELECT 
  UID, 
  Min(timecolumn) AS `In Time`, 
  Max(timecolumn)  AS `Out Time`,
  TIMEDIFF(Max(timecolumn), Min(timecolumn)) AS `Time Diff`
FROM demotable 
GROUP BY UID, DATE(timecolumn)
```

Comment: yes, but I need same day time difference with this you get from start to end data from the full table. **I need first and last entry of the day **

Comment: hey @forpas thank you, you really save my day but can you help me a bit with this I get correct out but userid wise can I get date wise output?

Comment: You can use MONTH() in a WHERE clause if you want, like `WHERE MONTH(date) = 3` if this is what you need, but this will return all rows for month = 3 of every year. You should do: `WHERE MONTH(date) = 3 AND YEAR(date) = 2019`

Comment: `TIMEDIFF()` is buggy, because it ignores DST (daytime saving time). Examples for CET: `select timediff("2019-03-31 04:00","2019-03-31 02:00")` returns the wrong result `02:00:00`, but `select unix_timestamp("2019-03-31 04:00")-unix_timestamp("2019-03-31 02:00")` returns the correct difference `3600`. So I recommend to store dates always as `int = UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`.

Answer (score 0):

For the same day time difference, you can use group by clause.
    As per your output- same day no out time, then don't show that row- for this you can use HAVING clause by checking max(time) is not equal to min(time) for the same day.

```sql
SELECT 
  UID, 
  Min(Time) AS `In Time`, 
  Max(Time)  AS `Out Time`,
  TIMEDIFF(Max(Time), Min(Time)) AS `Time Diff`
FROM demo                          
GROUP BY UID, DATE(Time)  
HAVING Max(Time) != Min(Time)
```

you can see the working demo too
[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v1FPpTKckDvKkCx6XFqczg/0)

Comment: Logic !! But can I add WHERE Time BETWEEN '2019-01-30' and '2019-02-30' " with this so I add date wise filter?